# Windows 8 Mail unable to open

Tags: email-client, windows-8, windows-mail

When I click Mail from the "metro" screen the fullscreen interface appears for 2 seconds, then closes and returns me back to the metro screen. I am unable to open Mail. I tried removing and re-installing the application from the Windows 8 store, didn't help. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You probably have an nVidia card, which needs new drivers.

Comment: @RandolphWest I do, but I updated to the latest Windows 8 drivers this morning. Do I need something newer?

Comment: Did you get them from Windows Update or nvidia.com?

Comment: @RandolphWest nvidia.com

Comment: What resolution are you using? And what Win8 version (RTM, preview,...)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you do a fresh install or upgrade from Windows 7? I had the same problem including this and other Metro apps and the only solution that worked for me was a clean Win8 install.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using [Raptr](http://raptr.com/)? It appears to have caused this to quite a lot of ppl on [this thread](http://www.eightforums.com/browsers-mail/8390-mail-app-crashing-startup.html) and [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lt-LT/w8itprogeneral/thread/790a63f8-f9e7-472f-a20f-d86a10cdc33c)

Otherwise, there are some debugging steps you can follow at [Microsoft community forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/everytime-i-open-my-mail-app-it-crashes/9d705397-e93e-4791-a192-1f9deb145898?msgId=8483140c-408b-4ee7-a8cd-0440786177b8)